# Progress bar on web view loading

Tags: android

У меня есть фрагмент

```
public class BookFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_fragment, container, false);
        WebView webView = (WebView )view.findViewById(R.id.book_webView);
        webView.loadUrl("***");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Нужно подключить progress bar при загрузке содержимого сайта, и удалить после. Пробовал подключать ProgressDialog, но выдает ошибку

Comment: Вам нужно переопределить базовый WebViewClient и переопределить его методы onPageStarted и OnPageFinished. Cам progressbar добавьте в layout и скрывайте или показуйте в onPageStarted и OnPageFinished

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Android WebView как добавить индикатор загрузки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679144/android-webview-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать метод onProgressChanged в WebChromeClient:

```
    ProgressBar progressBar = (WebView )view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    //Ваш WebView
    WebView webView = (WebView )view.findViewById(R.id.book_webView);
    //Добавляем WebChromeClient
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if(progress < 100 && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }

            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            if(progress == 100) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Код несколько сложноват, достаточно написать что-то вроде: `progressBar?.isVisible = newProgress < 100` `progressBar?.progress = newProgress`. Также нужно проверить, что progressBar существует. Т.к. мы можем выйти из фрагмента до завершения загрузки страницы, что может привести к крэшу.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar7).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar7).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            view.findViewById(R.id.book_webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```