# Android WebView как добавить индикатор загрузки

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Перехожу я в webview по ссылке и мне нужен индикатор загрузки страницы, чтобы знать сколько осталось и вообще загружаеться она или нет.
Как это сделать. Мне не нужно объяснять про progressbar и всё такое, мне нужно узнать как вытащить прогресс загрузки из WebView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прогресс можно получить, установив веб вью кастомный `WebChromeClient`:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        progress; // от 0 до 100
    }
});
```

Comment: А что прописать внутри onProgressChanged?

Comment: Вы же сами написали, что вам не нужно объяснять про `ProgressBar`, а нужно только вытащить прогресс из веб вью. Ну вот в переменной `int progress` и будет прогресс. Дальше делайте с ним что хотите.

Comment: Аааа тогда понятно...